# What Event Happens on iOS Safari When Font Size Is Changed

Tags: ios, safari

I have a web page that needs to adjust the width of a div if the font size is changed on Safari on iOS. That is when tapping the "aA" on the address bar and selecting a different zoom level.

In the past I found that the "scroll" event fires when changing the zoom level. This seems a bit extreme as whenever a scroll happens, my code is called.

Does anyone know if there is a more appropriate event that is fired when the zoom level is changed on Safari on iOS?